# Simple PHP & MySQL Problem - COUNT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm messing around with a little statistics tool. My DB looks like this:

```
ip           | campaign_id | authorized | stamp
-----------------------------------------------------
182.74.723.1 | 1           | 0          | 12349210211
82.14.127.1  | 3           | 1          | 29834043899
```

I want to have a line saying:

*There are "XXX" hits on Campaign with ID "X" ("XXX" were authorized, "XXX" were not authorized)*

My code so far:

```
$query = "SELECT campaign_id, COUNT(ip) FROM stats GROUP BY campaign_id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "There are <b>". $row['COUNT(ip)'] ." hits</b> on campaign with <b>ID ". $row['campaign_id'] ."</b> (HERE COMES THE PART I'M LOOKING FOR)";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Now the problem: I couldn't find a solution to count the different values of "auth".
I'd be so happy if anyone could help me out in this one, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
    SELECT campaign_id, 
    COUNT(ip) as tot,
    sum(authorized=0) as a0,
    sum(authorized=1) as a1,
    ....
    FROM stats GROUP BY campaign_id
```